# Can Excel's "drag to move data" feature be disabled?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Excel has a feature where selected data can be *moved* if you hover over the edge of the data selection outline, then left click and drag. To be clear, I'm *not* talking about the feature where data can be *expanded* by dragging the slightly larger green square at the bottom right of a selection.

E.g. I can grab this green outline anywhere other than the lower right corner and drag these numbers elsewhere:

[image]

E.g. I can drag them down one row:

[image]

If I try to drag them onto existing data, there's a warning that they're going to replace existing data:

[image]

(Sorry, Windows Snip is not showing the mouse which would make this clearer)

The thing is, in ~20 years of very heavy Excel use I've *never* used this feature, and lately for some reason I find I'm frequently invoking it accidentally just from navigating around spreadsheets. I don't know if it's an issue with a more sensitive mouse button or something about the arrangement of quantity of data in my spreadsheets, but it's really annoying me. I'm having to cancel that confirmation multiple times a day.

**My question is, is there any way to disable the drag to move data feature completely?** So that the only thing you can do with that outline is *expand* the data.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, see, in the settings. See https://www.geekyard.com/how-to/how-to-enable-or-disable-cell-drag-and-drop-editing-option-in-ms-excel/ or  https://ms-office.wonderhowto.com/how-to/disable-quick-fill-handle-drag-drop-excel-features-338734/ Agreed, dragging-and-dropping text in*all* Office apps is a PITA.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following macros (in a sheet module):

```
Dim sel As String
Dim stopundo As String
Dim tc As Double

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Application.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   If stopundo <> "N" Then
      tc = Target.CountLarge
      stopundo = "N"
   ElseIf Target.Address <> sel And Target.CountLarge = tc Then
      MsgBox "cannot drag-and-drop"
      stopundo = "Y"
      Application.Undo
   End If
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
      sel = Selection.Address
      tc = Selection.CountLarge
   End If
End Sub
```

If you want to `Cut` and `Paste` some cells you must select destination range larger or smaller than the source range.